# Show realtime video stream in Delphi XE6 with Indy 10

Tags: delphi, video-streaming, indy, indy10

I am wondering if it is possible to show realtime video stream using Indy 10. I have a client program that can send video in .h264/.mjpeg/.avi etc. format as a memory stream, but I don't know how to show it in my server program.

The client program is written in Python on a Raspberry Pi, and my server program will be written in Delphi, XE6.

Comment: Indy won't render you a video stream. Why, or how do you want to involve Indy for this task ? A video player control based e.g. on DirectShow embedded in your app. should be enough for this, I think (your application is actually a client from what you've described; server is the side that is serving the stream).

Comment: I suppose that first of all you need to decide on a streaming protocol. Have you done that? Wouldn't it be easier to use VLC?

Comment: I need to send the video over LAN so I thought that I could use Indys TCP or UDP components, but I have no idea how to process and show the stream in Delphi. I will look into DirectShow, thanks for the tip.